# How to dispatch a separate custom action in react-admin?

Tags: redux, admin-on-rest, react-admin

I want to dispatch a plain `redux` action of my own choosing on app startup, and trap it in a custom saga, within an `<Admin>` app. I've read the doc about [custom action creators](https://marmelab.com/admin-on-rest/Actions.html#using-a-custom-action-creator) but (a) it only describes how to plug this to subcomponents using the `react-admin` infrastructure, and (b) using `connect` in `App.js` crashes the app because it `Could not find "store" in either the context or props of "Connect(App)"`. I can't `wrap the root component in a <Provider>, or explicitly pass "store" as a prop to "Connect(App)"` as it suggests, because I can't find any way to get a reference to the `redux` store used in `react-admin`.

How do I get hold of the `store`, so I can just dispatch e.g. `{ type: 'MY_CUSTOM_ACTION' }` to it? Do I have to make a completely [Custom App](https://marmelab.com/admin-on-rest/CustomApp.html)? Seems a lot of overhead when all I want is to dispatch a really simple action to an existing `redux` store. `react-admin` has hooks already in place for custom reducers and custom sagas to *handle* any type of action, but I can't find anything to *dispatch* them with.

Thanks!

Comment: BTW, if there's an existing 'on app startup' action I can catch in my saga, that'd work fine for my current issue. (I couldn't find a reliable one even by doing `takeEvery('*')` and seeing all actions). But I'm still interested to know how to dispatch custom actions via the store.

Comment: What you are trying to achieve is a side effect. Sagas are here to handle side effects. Just create a custom saga that dispatches an action upon start.